# How to load a CSV into IPython notebook

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, ipython

I have a csv file ready to load into my python code, however, I want to load it into the following format:

```
data = [[A,B,C,D],
        [A,B,C,D],
        [A,B,C,D],
       ]
```

How would I go about loading a .csv file that is readable as a numpy array? e.g., simply using previous tutorials plays havoc with using:

```
data = np.array(data)
```

Failing that, I would just like to upload my csv file (e.g. 'dual-Cored.csv' as data = dual-Cored.csv)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest solution is just:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("myfile.csv")
```

As long as the data is convertible into `float` and has an equal number of columns on each row, this works.

If the data is not convertible into `float` in some column, you may write your own converters for it. Please see the `numpy.loadtxt` documentation. It is really very flexible.

Comment: @user3125347 Where does IPython notebook import the csv file from?

Answer (score 2):

If your CVS looks like this:

```
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```

then

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

would make `data` equal to

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Comment: This works, however, I want it in the form: [[A,B,C],[A,B,C]]. I don't want the quotation marks.

Comment: @user3125347 the quotes indicate strings; if your data aren't numbers, they aren't optional.

Comment: Hi, i have exactly the same data structure in my csv file as in your examle above.  im using your above code just substituting the file name with my own and trying to read the csv file on my jupyter notebook. it says no such file or directory 'file name'. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As a small example, I have some file `data.csv` with the following contents.

> A,B,C,D
>   1,2,3,4
>   W,X,Y,Z
>   5,6,7,8

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = [i.split(",") for i in f.read().split()]
    print data
```

Output

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
 ['5', '6', '7', '8']]
```

Comment: @user3125347 what do you mean "readable by numpy"? This is the format you asked for, and numpy can certainly deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean to get all your data points as integers or floating point numbers.

First I wrote some sample data:

```
with open('dual-Cored.csv', 'w') as f:     
    f.write('1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8\n9,10,11,12')
```

Now I'm reading back in the sample data

```
with open('dual-Cored.csv', 'rU') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f)
    for l in c:
         print list(map(int, l))
```

Which prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I recommend you read up a bit on [datatypes in the Python tutorial, which talks about the difference between strings and numerical types.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

To read into a numpy array with the csv module:

```
import numpy
with open('dual-Cored.csv', 'rU') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f)
    ar = numpy.array(list(c), dtype=int)
```

and `ar` now returns:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Or directly use the `numpy.genfromtxt` function (you'll need to specify the delimiter):

```
numpy.genfromtxt('dual-Cored.csv', delimiter=',')
```

returns:

```
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.,  12.]])
```

Comment: if the target is a numpy array, why not directly using numpy.loadtxt?