# why do i get a nameerror when i try to load a CSV-File in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, nameerror

my csv file has the following structure:

```
 ID    fromEmail   ID toEmail
 134     a@a.com   23  b@b.com
 33      aa@a.com  323 bbb@b.com
```

i have the following code on my jupyter notebook:

```
 import csv as pt
 with open(dnc-temporalGraph.csv, 'rb') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

and the following NameError:

```
     NameError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-65-1b0399e4e4b5> in <module>()
           1 import csv as pt
     ----> 2 with open(dnc-temporalGraph.csv, 'rb') as f:
           3     data = list(csv.reader(f))

     NameError: name 'dnc' is not defined
```

i've checked out some other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853632/how-to-load-a-csv-into-ipython-notebook) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414060/open-csv-file-with-python-throws-nameerror/40414133) but still couldn't figure out what im doing wrong here. if i put the filename between single quotation marks as in the second link, then i get an IOError

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dnc-temporalGraph.csv'
```

help please?

Comment: Use `with open('dnc-temporalGraph.csv', 'rb')`, you forgot the `' '` on on the name for your file

Comment: no i didn't. read above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the file name as a string:

```
with open("dnc-temporalGraph.csv", 'rb') as f:
```

Otherwise it will think you are calling a variable `dnc`

Make sure the notebook is in the same location as your `csv`. If it's not in the same location you have to give the full path: `"C:/user/x/file_name.csv"`

---

Lastly you are importing csv as `pt`

Either get rid of `as pt` or change the entry `"csv.reader(f)"` to `"pt.reader(f)"`

---

So your code should be:

```
import csv as pt
with open("dnc-temporalGraph.csv", 'rb') as f:
   data = list(pt.reader(f))
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. but that doesnt help. my notebook and the csv file are in the same folder. when i put the file between double quotation marks as you suggestet, then i get the NameError again. but this time it says    "NameError: name 'csv' is not defined"

Comment: Ah then it's working. And you haven't defined `csv` because you import it as pt. So replace `csv` with `pt`

Comment: oh thanks! that really solved the problem. but according to my assignment description im supposed to import csv as pt. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: dont use call `csv` call `pt` instead